# MongoDB: How to stop and resume change stream

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, changestream

How to stop a mongodb changestream temporarily and resume it again?

```
public Flux<Example> watch() {
  final ChangeStreamOptions changeStreamOptions = ChangeStreamOptions.builder().returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build();
  return reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("collection", changeStreamOptions, Example.class)
          .filter(e -> e.getOperationType() != null)
          .mapNotNull(ChangeStreamEvent::getBody);
}
```

I'm trying to create a rest endpoint that should be able to stop the changestream for sometime while we do some database maintenance and then invoke the endpoint again to resume the stream from where it left off using resume token.

Comment: Did you have a look at resume tokens? You could save the token when stream is closed and then save the token in some persistent store. Then when you launch the app again you just get the last token and resume from the saved position. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveChangeStreamOperation.ResumingChangeStream.html)

Comment: yes, the resume token is being stored but after that, looking for a way to close the stream gracefully and start it again without restarting the app

Answer (score 0):

I am not a MongoDB expert but this is what I understood from one, hope I got it right and I am using the plain Java driver API for easier readability:

```
// 1. Open, consume, close, save token
MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor = inventoryCollection.watch().iterator();
ChangeStreamDocument<Document> next = cursor.next()
BsonDocument resumeToken = next.getResumeToken();
cursor.close();

// 2. Save the resume token in the database, in case your process goes down for any reason during your pause. Otherwise, you will not know where to start resuming.
...

// 3. When you want to reopen again start from the DB saved resumeToken
cursor = inventoryCollection.watch().resumeAfter(resumeToken).iterator();
```

The time window from the moment you receive the event until you save it should be very small but it may happen the process crashes before you save the continuation _id. If you have operations that are sensitive to that time window, then those operations should be idempotent so that in case you replay an already received event your data will not be affected.

It would have been nice for the Mongo server to keep track of the current offset for all change streams and uniquely identify clients. This is not possible now and this is why Mongo provides and asks for the resume token.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to unsubscribe/stop changestream

```
Disposable subscription = service.watch()
       .subscribe(exampleService::doSomething)

// cancel the subscription       
subscription.dispose();
```